mystery tree/shrub with red leaves
I have a small shrub/tree with red single leaves and grey white fuzzy berry-like fruits which are green on the inside. Before the fruits it had strange reddish pink flowers. Does anyone have any idea what plant it is? Thank you for your assistance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The Bonfire peach tree (Prunus persica 'Bonfire') is a dwarf cultivar of the peach tree, prized for its ornamental features rather than its fruit. It is a hybrid resulting from crossing various Prunus species, likely including peaches, nectarines, and ornamental flowering peaches.

Characteristics

Compact size: The Bonfire peach tree is a dwarf variety, typically
reaching only 5-8 feet tall and wide at maturity. This makes it a
great choice for small gardens or even container planting.
Showy flowers: In early spring, the Bonfire peach tree produces
double pink flowers with deep pink centers.
Dark red foliage: The most striking feature of the Bonfire peach tree
is its foliage. The leaves emerge a deep red in spring and mature to
a rich burgundy color. This dark foliage holds its color well
throughout the growing season.
Fruit: The Bonfire peach tree produces fruit, but the peaches are
small and not flavorful. They are best left on the tree for
ornamental purposes or used for making jams and jellies.

